# Сброс выбора элемента ListView при выборе этого элемента

Tags: c#, maui

У меня имеется `ListView` (диалоги), при нажатии на элемент происходит переход на страницу диалога. Проблема в том, что при возвращении на страницу с `ListView` у выбранного ранее элемента отличная от других подсветка + при клике на него переход не происходит (он активен, судя по всему), как можно перезагрузить этот `ListView`, чтобы возможность выбора этого элемента вернулась?

Попробовал это сделать через переопределение `OnAppearing` и `OnDisappearing`:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    OnPropertyChanged();
}
```

В общем, это не помогло. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать правильно, и вообще стоит ли мне  под такие цели использовать `ListView`? Спасибо.

Comment: Поймите наконец одну вещь - у вас должно быть все разделено на слои: Model - слой данных, View - слой UI, ViewModel - связующий слой. Это зовется все MVVM подходом, и если вы его начали использовать (а по названиям из предыдущих вопросов так и есть), то используйте дальше. При таком подходе у вас не должно вообще быть желания трогать UI, вот прям вообще. Выделена кнопка? Что надо сделать? Правильно, изменить привязанное к ней свойство на нужную вам, например страницу (или что там), тогда UI сам уберет выделение, или поставит его на нужный объект за вас. И да, не бросайте старые вопросы!

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged();` это что? Оно вызываться должно из сеттера свойства, либо в скобках должно быть указано имя свойства, для которого оно вызывается.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, хорошо, попробую это сделать таким образом

Comment: @aepot, спасибо)